# Where does the figure that Esdeath killed 400,000 Northerners by burying them alive come from?

Tags: akame-ga-kill

Where does this figure come from? From the [wiki](https://akamegakill.fandom.com/wiki/Northern_Tribes) of Northern tribes, it states she buries 400,000 northerners at once and then breaks and kills their hero, Numa Seika.

In the manga, I see her kill the hero in Ch. 7 and in Ch. 10 we see Esdeath's 3 henchmen throw tribesmen into a pit to be buried alive. It doesn't directly state northern tribesmen but even if they were northerners, where does this 400,000 number arrive from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It's on manga chapter 8 and anime episode 5.**

The number "400,000" was mentioned when the Emperor was describing Esdeath after the recommendation from the Prime Minister.

Manga chapter 8

> [image]
>
> She (Esdeath)'s as great a hero as Budo. It should be fine! **She's a woman of ice who buried 400,000 tribe members alive!!**

Anime episode 5

> [image]
>
> With her dominion over ice, **she buried over four hundred thousand northerners alive.**